# How to create a WebSocket server in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

According to [Minimal server example](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/networking/websocket.html#minimal-server-example) in the networking tutorials, there should be a `WebSocketServer` class; however, I don't see any at the [API reference](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/index.html).

> ```
> # Our WebSocketServer instance
> var _server = WebSocketServer.new()
> ```

It is outdated by the way, but then which is the way now?

---

In respect to the GitHub example @Theraot linked, I'm having an issue that when two or more peers are connected in environment and I close one of them, the `self.stop_scheduled = ...` assignment below unexpectedly executes:

```
# When a client connects to the server
self.server.client_connected.connect(func(peer_id: int):
    var peer := Peer.new(peer_id)
    self.peers[peer_id] = peer)

# When a client disconnects from the server
self.server.client_disconnected.connect(func(peer_id: int):
    var peer := self.peers[peer_id] as Peer
    peer.car.get_parent().remove_child(peer.car)
    self.peers.erase(peer_id)
    if self.peers.is_empty():
        self.stop_scheduled = StopScheduled.now())
```

When I replace this `self.stop_scheduled = ...` assignment by `pass` and print `peer_id` out of the `if`, and disconnect two peers, I get something like:

> 54931822
> 470091519

Debug code:

```
# When a client disconnects from the server
self.server.client_disconnected.connect(func(peer_id: int):
    var peer := self.peers[peer_id] as Peer
    peer.car.get_parent().remove_child(peer.car)
    self.peers.erase(peer_id)
    print(peer_id)
    if self.peers.is_empty():
        # self.stop_scheduled = StopScheduled.now()
        pass)
```

Comment: Yes, that is obsolete... Try this: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-demo-projects/tree/master/networking/websocket_chat (yes I know the README says GLES2, but apparently the code has been updated to Godot 4).

Comment: @Theraot I'm having a little issue when I close a peer when two or more are present. Any idea?

Comment: did you check, that the peer_id in your signal is changing for each socket? Just a thought. If they all have the same ID you would only override the same entry on each connection.

Comment: @Bugfish Added data!